# Image preprocessing and clustering using SciKit-Image and SciKit-Learn - some advice needed

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, scikit-image

I have a whole bunch of images of official documents from the 1930-40s, both colour and B&W, which are of fairly low quality (generally generally < 250 kB). These are photos of standard forms used by official institutions such as hospitals and municipalities and the like, that have been filled out by hand or by typewriter with personal information. I have placed two typical examples at the end of this post. (Note that these are empty forms - I'd rather not place the ones with personal information online.)

What I need to do is order the collection so that all documents of the same type are grouped together. I don't know how many different types there are. Alternatively, I could first experiment with trying to find all instantiations of one particular document type. I imagine that the former approach is a clustering approach, whereas the latter is a similarity approach.

Regarding the clustering approach, my idea is (1) to preprocess the images to enhance the useful information, (2) extract a feature vector from each image, and (3) feed these feature vectors to a clustering algorithm. I want to use the SciKit-Image and SciKit-Learn libraries for these three tasks. I've done a bit of research and reading up to get familiar with the topic and the possibilities, but I don't know where to start and have some basic questions.

- **Preprocessing**. Which are the methods that have shown to be useful? There are so many options: binarisation, grayscaling, deskewing, denoising, blurring, cropping, scaling, ...
- **Feature extraction**. I imagine that it is helpful if the most interesting characteristics of an image (corners, lines, grids, pictures, logos) are  captured in a feature vector - in other words, if the features are based on so-called interest points. Again, are there specific methods that have proven to be helpful in this respect? What is the best way to represent an image as a feature vector, and how do I extract the interesting characteristics?
- **Clustering**. I see that SciKit-Learn offers several clustering algorithms. Which ones would be the most suitable for my task? And which ones are the most suitable to start with - something like k-means?

Regarding the similarity task, I don't have a clear idea how to approach this, or if this even possible. *Any* help is welcome...

I realise that this is a fairly broad question. In general, I would like to receive some feedback on whether my approach makes any sense, and whether it is likely to yield useful results. Furthermore, I would highly appreciate any pointers to examples, existing pipelines, or general good advice!

Examples:

[image: Example form 1]

[image: Example form 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your task would be much easier if you identified the number of document types by hand and then tried to find matches by determining the similarity to your identified categories.

As a similarity index, I would pursue one of two strategies:

1) Image registration based on the constant parts of the forms.

2) Matching on phrases / keywords. From your example, "Antrag auf Krankenhausaufname" is easily extracted from the image via pytesseract, even without any pre-processing of the image:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open("test.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="deu")

print text
```

This yields:

> ```
> Zur Bendmmg für den Veru'dxerlenl ’
>
> Die." Antragudm’n in! der Krln Iren In n: vor
> Au/wdum du Krankenhnu an zlnzuru'dlem
>
> Antrag auf Krankenhausaufnahme
>
> ._ ‚x, - >
>
> A Namp des Mitgligds:
> V'orname: - '
>
> Ehefrau: „_
> Kind :
>
> Arbeitgeber :
> Behandelt seit arbeitsgnfähig seit
>
> Gehikhlq? ja _ nein i s
> Belördemnq durch Kunkenkranwagen — Mxelklahwagen — Ist
> ‘ -- nichl — eﬂordarllch. r- „ -
> Arbeilsunh‘” Folge eine: Irüheren Arbgttsunlalls’l Un‘allvemlcheﬂe
> Berulxkvankheiﬂ Verkghßq Spodunlall. Schlägerei. Trunksuchﬂ
> VevsorgungslaideI-J Fundemwirkung? Folge emer Irühercn. nichl
> behobene" Krankhen7
>
> .AZuInﬁmJn Inlmmidnn g
>
> Krankheitsbezeichnung ')x WM.-."
>
> /
>
>
>
> Begründung: __.___.
> ```

Clearly, you could match document by matching phrases that you know are reliably extracted from the document by tesseract.

Comment: Excellent! This comes closest to the solution I'm looking for. I have fiddled with Tesseract but didn't know about Pytesseract.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing:
You can do, grayscale, denoise, remove border and deskew. Should be enough for my plan to work.

1. Resize the image to match some usually occurring format like A4, but take care to conserve aspect ratio of the image.
2. You DO find interest points and crop them out. That way you are considering only form fields, not entries which can vary.
3. You make a fingerprint per each interest point of a document.
4. You construct a whole image fingerprint from all those individual ones.
5. Just sort all fingerprints, no sophisticated clustering needed.
6. In sorted list of fingerprints, find out somehow where one group of documents ends and another begins and separate them.

And you are done!

If you go for clustering etc. the process will be much slower and result will be the same. Well depends on clustering algo, and what kind of feature vector are you going to feed to it. But this should be faster, and neater to program as well.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering such data will be very difficult. k-means is very sensitive to bad data points, so don't think it will work well. But it will depend very much on the quality of your features.

I don't think standard features like SIFT will be of much use. They are meant for photographs with gradients and such.

You will need to carefully craft the features, e.g. amount of horizontal lines vs. Amount of vertical lines, background hue, etc. And then experiment with *robust* clustering algorithms such as DBSCAN and hierarchical clustering. The latter may be an easier starting point, but harder to scale.